# matplotlib file open dialog

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib navigation tool bar for example, there exists a button to save figure to a png which opens up a file open dialog. I believe this file open dialog works regardless of the backend being used.

[image]

I would like to use this functionality within my code. How do I call this file open dialog ***depending completely on matplotlib WITHOUT importing Qt or TkInter ?***

I have had a look at the navigation tool bar source code [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/d888c07412c141b05e58212b74fba4c4b1847497/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py#L696) but it appears that savefig function calls "_getSaveFileName" which is directly imported from Qt.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

from matplotlib.backends import qt_compat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()

file, _ = qt_compat._getSaveFileName(fig.canvas.parent(),
    caption = "Save a txt", filter ='*.txt')
```